# Cannot configure Postfix to receive mail

Tags: postfix, centos

I try to configure Postfix on CentOs 6. I can send mails from the server just fine, but cannot receive.

The Delivery Status Notification that I get is:

```
The error that the other server returned was:
550 5.1.1 <user@mydomain.com>: Recipient address rejected:
User unknown in virtual alias table
```

I have used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-postfix-on-centos-6) to setup postfix.
The content of `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file is:

```
soft_bounce             = no
queue_directory         = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory       = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory        = /usr/libexec/postfix
mail_owner              = postfix

# The default_privs parameter specifies the default rights used by
# the local delivery agent for delivery to external file or command.
# These rights are used in the absence of a recipient user context.
# DO NOT SPECIFY A PRIVILEGED USER OR THE POSTFIX OWNER.
#
#default_privs = nobody

myhostname              = mail.mydomain.com 
mydomain                = mydomain.com

mydestination           = $myhostname, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

mynetworks_style        = host
mailbox_transport       = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp
local_destination_recipient_limit       = 300
local_destination_concurrency_limit     = 5
recipient_delimiter=+

virtual_alias_maps      = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

header_checks           = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks      = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks
smtpd_banner            = $myhostname

debug_peer_level        = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path           = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path         = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path              = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group            = postdrop
html_directory          = no
manpage_directory       = /usr/share/man
sample_directory        = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
readme_directory        = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable          = yes
smtpd_sasl_application_name     = smtpd
smtpd_recipient_restrictions    = permit_sasl_authenticated,
                                  permit_mynetworks,
                                  reject_unauth_destination,
                                  reject_invalid_hostname,
                                  reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
                                  reject_non_fqdn_sender,
                                  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
                                  reject_unknown_sender_domain,
                                  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                                  reject_unauth_pipelining,
                                  reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
                                  reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
                                  reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org,
                                  reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
                                  permit

smtpd_sasl_security_options     = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain         = 
broken_sasl_auth_clients        = yes

smtpd_helo_required             = yes
```

The content of `/etc/postfix/virtual` file is:

```
user@mydomain.com   mydomain.com/user
```

In `/var/log/maillog` I don't see any information about this problem.
I am new to  Linux, and I would like to know how to debug or how can I fix this issue.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: first of all you need to have working dns, second you need to have working email created on your domain ..

Comment: @vladeli I think that DNS records are all right. `host -t MX mydomain.com` points to `mail.mydomain.com` and  `host -t A mail.mydomain.com` points to my server IP. About what that you say "you need to have working email created on your domain" - what do you mean?

Comment: Does the unix user "user" exist? Or is it defined in the virtual alias table to map to some user? What docs have you tried that didn't give the expected result?

Comment: @Marki Yes it is. I can see this user in /etc/passwd. I deal with this problem for two days, I went through a few instructors. Meanwhile, nothing helps.

Comment: So, what does /etc/postfix/virtual contain? Since that is the error message at large.

Comment: @Marki `user@mydomain.com   mydomain.com/user`

Comment: Where does it say to put `mydomain.com/user` on the right-hand side? Did you run postmap after updating the file? Again: what guides did you follow?

Comment: @Marki It's in `/var/spool/mail` (I hope it's right). After updating I do reload postfix, also, after updating `virtual` I run `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`. I followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-postfix-on-centos-6

Comment: Umm, did you mean `conf.cf` or is that a typo? Should be main.cf

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. I mean main.cf

Comment: Still not finding the logs is not an excuse either. `grep -r postfix /var/log`

Comment: @Marki I tried it again. And I see that there are no records in logs about mails that I send to server. I see only records of reloading postfix.

Comment: If there are no logs of your attempts and you believe logging is alright and you know where and how to look, then only one thing remains: mails are not arriving at your server. So go check everything from the beginning. Dns, ips, services, hell use tcpdump on port 25 to see what's happening if you must.

Comment: @Marki Thank you very much for your help. I tried to listen to port 25 with tcpdump, and I see that it catches emails that I send to server. I will try to understand this data, and will try to debug the issue.